# .click function for an object inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, click, selector

I'm starting in JS and JQuery, and I just need a bit of help.
I want to scroll a page (this is ok), but when a button is clicked. This button has the class "testelement" and is inside an iframe. So I want the main page to be scrolled when a button inside the iframe is clicked. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work. I'm sure it's a stupid mistake at the first line, but I don't know...

```
$('iframe').contents().find('.testelement').click(function() {
    $('body').animate({ scrollTop: 1000 }, 2000);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the iframe source of the same domain as the parent page?

Comment: Error in the console? Does the click fire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is reference the parent window. See this link [window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent), for more information. Using jQuery, you can try the following. Hope this helps:

$('body', window.parent.document).animate({ scrollTop: 1000 }, 2000);;

**EDIT :**

From the parent window, you can access the button in the iframe (assuming same origin), like this---pretty much just what you wrote above:

```
$("#MyIframe").contents().find("#scroller").click(function(){
    $('body').animate({ scrollTop: 1000 }, 2000);
}
```

'#scroller' is the ID of the button on the iframe (or whatever unique selector you want to use).

Comment: Hi ! The problem is that the paged in the iframe is generated by a software (adobe edge), so I need to add a script to the main frame, and get the click event from an element of the iframe. By the way, hanks for your awnser.

Comment: Are both the pages you're working with served from the same domain? If not, you may run into a permissions issue:  [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Yes, both pages are on my computer for the moment ! I'm going to try to put them on a server.

Comment: Of course, you may be able to avoid all of this hassle by not using an iframe to begin with. Is there a reason you need to use an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

If the click is actually working that you should look at doing the animate this way

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "1000px" }, 2000);
```

Comment: Is the syntax of the first line ok ? It's this one that doesn't works, because when I write this in the page :

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('body').animate({ scrollTop: 1000 }, 2000);
    });

the animation starts when the page is loaded...

Comment: Are you adding the click event after the page contents is fully loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody, I finally solved my problem !

I asked this question because I tried, and it was impossible to click any button in the iframe. I tried so many things... I became crazy when I discovered that I just had to put it on a server instead of running it locally. I felt so stupid !

FOR EVERY USER OF ADOBE WEB GENERATING SOFTWARES (like ADOBE MUSE, ADOBE EDGE) :

If we run a preview of our work, the software creates a "fake" server, and it works great. But when we generate the final html code, problems happens... It's really often a problem that happens because we're running our page locally.

I hope I helped people